# How to traverse a list of words and search each word and count the occurrences of a given substring within the word?

Tags: python

I need to define a function called `freq_count(substr,list)`. This function accepts a `str` and a list of words as arguments. It traverses the list of words and searches each word and counts the occurrences of the substring `substr` within the `word`. Print each word along with the number of substring occurrences found.

Here is my code:

```
def freq_count(substr,list):
     start_po = 0
     count = 0
     for word in list:
         if word.find(str(substr)) != -1:
             start_po = word.find(str,start_po)
             count = count + 1
     return(str(word) + str(count))
```

Comment: Please do not shout or put everything in boldface in your question.

Comment: Say you search `aa` and a word in the list is `aaa` for how many occurences does this count? One or two?

Comment: Thank you so much. It counts as 1 occurrences.

Comment: and `aa` in `aaaa` counts for two?

Comment: Yes. That counts for two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have to **iterate** over the list of `words` and **count** the number of occurrences  for each word in the list, and print them.

Now `print`ing and `return`ing are two different tasks. The above statement however already defines a skeleton for the function you aim to implement:

```
def freq_count(substr,list):
    for word in list:
        count = 0
        while ...: #we find an occurence
            count += 1
        print(word+str(count))
```

The only thing we still have to implement is an occurrence check. You already partly solved this by using the `find` method. The only problem is that we need to iterate until we find no more occurrences. We thus need a **variable** that keeps track of the position we currently have in the word, a variable we will call `pos`. `pos` is added to the structure as follows:

```
def freq_count(substr,list):
    for word in list:
        count = 0
        pos = word.find(substr)
        while pos >= 0:#we find an occurence
            count += 1
            pos += len(substr)
            pos = word.find(substr,pos)
        print(word+str(count))
```

How does this work? The first time we call [`word.find(substr)`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_find.htm) it will search for the *first* occurence of `substr` in `word`. If no such substring exists, `pos` will be equal to `-1`. In that case the `while` loop fails immediately, and thus no counting is done, the result is zero in that case.

In the case we found an occurrence, `pos` will be equal to the index where the substring start. We increment the `count` because we found one occurrence, and we update `pos`: first we add the length `len(substr)` of the substring `substr` to prevent we find any more occurrence that *partly  overlap* the previous occurrence. Next we call `find` again, but now we feed it a begin position `pos`. We thus only look for occurrence that start later or at `pos`. The `while` loop will repeat looping as long as there are more occurrences to be found.

**Demo (using `python3`)**:

```
>>> freq_count('aba',['','a','aba','ababa','abaaba','abababa','abacaba'])
0
a0
aba1
ababa1
abaaba2
abababa2
abacaba2
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it! I definitely benefit a lot from your detailed explanation.